# Почему SQL Server постоянно съедает все больше и больше памяти?

Tags: администрирование, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Ответьте, пожалуйста, если кто знает:
Установлен `Microsoft SQL Server 2005`. После перезапуска, он съедает примерно 100 метров оперативки. Потом, когда к нему начинается масса запросов, он начинает занимать в оперативной памяти все больше и больше места. И со временем, как я надеялся, он не освобождает память.
Вопрос: почему так происходит? И, если это зловредные процессы в нем происходят, то как с ними бороться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нормальное явление. Вы должны указать лимит памяти для сервера. Читайте документацию к MS SQL Server, раздел по [управлению параметрами памяти](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо большое. А не могли бы Вы ответить, на что SQL server отводит всю эту память.

Comment: Я не специалист по MSSQL Server, но, например, Oracle использует для кэширования данных, индексов, для того, чтобы увеличить размер видимого "окно" при обработке таблиц, для выполнения хранимых процедур (Oracle использует PLSQL очень активно даже на самом низком уровне). Думаю, MSSQL-серверу тоже есть куда память деть. Если же всё это обобщить, то одним словом можно сказать: оптимизация.

Comment: Все ясно, спасибо.